# How to read/write to a file that can be accessed by a user not being root?

Tags: java, android, file, storage-access-framework, google-pixel

I would like to write to a file that I can access from the file system without being root.

This is my attempt:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
final String FILE_NAME = "test.txt";

fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write("test".getBytes());

// Display path of file written to
Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to" + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Which writes to

```
/data/user/0/com.example.PROJECT_NAME/files/test.txt
```

which is not accessible without being root.

It would be good if there is a possibility to specify a different, absolute path which I know I can access, such as `/data/data/...`.

My device is a Google Pixel C which unfortunately has no external SD-Card slot to write to.

Comment: "which is not accessible without being root" -- that is accessible by your app without being root. It is not accessible by other apps or by the user without being root. "It would be good if there is a possibility to specify a different, absolute path which I know I can access, such as /data/data/..." -- `/data/data/...` is where you are writing, which is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). The paths seen by the app may not exactly match the paths seen by you in tools like Studio's Device File Explorer.

Comment: "My device is a Google Pixel C which unfortunately has no external SD-Card slot to write to." -- I agree that a Pixel C lacks a built-in option for [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). It does, however, have [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which you are welcome to use on Android 9 and older and to a lesser extent on Android 10 and higher.

Comment: Thank you! [This](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is exactly what helps me. I will now use the SAF (Storage Access Framework) for my problem. An [example implementation](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Storage_Access_Framework_Example) helps me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I figured out that the possibilities of accessing external storage differ quite a lot in different android versions, I chose to go with the Storage Access Framework (SAF). The SAF is an API (since API level 19), that offers the user a UI to browse through files.

Using an Intent, an UI pops up which lets the user create a file or choose an existing one:

```
private static final int CREATE_REQUEST_CODE = 40;
private Uri mFileLocation = null;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/plain"); // specify file type
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "newfile.txt"); // default name for file

startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After the user chose a file `onActivityResult(...)` gets called. Now it is possible to get the URI of the file by calling resultData.getData();

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == CREATE_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultData != null) {
                mFileLocation = resultData.getData();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Now use this URI to write to the file:

```
private void writeFileContent(Uri uri, String contentToWrite)
{
    try
    {
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w"); // or 'wa' to append

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
        fileOutputStream.write(contentToWrite.getBytes());

        fileOutputStream.close();
        pfd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```